# Ws-basic profile 1.0 vs Ws-basic profile 1.1

Tags: wcf

what is the difference between Ws-basic profile 1.0 and 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really tempted to answer Just f'n Google it:
http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1-2004-08-24.html#changes

Comment: I went through the link and now i have to question related to this. according to this there are two main difference between 1.0 and 1.1: 
* MESSAGE conformance target - Some requirements that had a MESSAGE conformance target in BP1.0 now use a new target, ENVELOPE. This facilitates alternate serialisations of the message, such as that described in the Attachments Profile.
* SOAP Binding - Requirements relating to the SOAP binding's serialization of the message have been moved to the Simple SOAP Binding Profile to facilitate other serializations.
can u explain these two points.